# Error with pre_match

Tags: php

I am still kinda noobie with pre_match. I am trying to get the pre_match used for a zip code this is the error I get when I go to the page.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/findstore.php on line

And this is my code:

```
<?php
    $zip;
    if (pre_match("/^[0-9]{5{$/", $zip)) {
        echo " The Zip code must be a 5-digit number.";
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Find Store</title>
    <style type="text/css" title="text/css" media="all">
        .error {
            color: #F30;
        }
        h3 {
            color: #00F;
        }
        body {
            background-color: # FFCF73;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="distance.php">
        <p>Zip: <input type="text" name="zip" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="find!"/></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I know I did something wrong and I have been going through it and everything. I am just wondering if someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think its `preg_match` not `pre_match`

Comment: pre_match? do you mean preg_match() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$zip; 
if (pre_match("/^[0-9]{5{$/", $zip)) { 
echo " The Zip code must be a 5-digit number."; 
}
?>
```

Pretty much everything about this is wrong. Try this instead:

```
<?php
if( preg_match("/^[0-9]{5}$/", $zip))
    $error = "The Zip code must be a 5-digit number.";
?>
<!DOCTYPE .........
....
....
<?php echo $error ?>
```

Things corrected:

1. removed extra space at the beginning of the script
2. pre***g***_match spelled correctly
3. regex had `{` in place of `}`
4. error message printed in the document, not somewhere before the doctype

Answer (score -1):

In:

```
pre_match("/^[0-9]{5{$/", $zip)) {
```

Use single quotes like:

```
pre_match('/^[0-9]{5{$/', $zip)) {
```

I did not check the rest of your code.

See: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing for more about what a $ means inside double quotes.